# Selenium failing on java (speed issues)

Tags: selenium

If I run the HTML version of the file, it works on slow mode (but fails on fast).

I tried using the setspeed method for java, but that didn't work (probably because it was depreciated in later versions). Then I tried adding manual thread weight times (before the spots where it fails), but it's failing for that also.

Anyway, here is my java code:

```
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestBase;

public class tradePagesNotLoad extends SeleneseTestBase{
private Selenium selenium;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    String baseUrl = "http://www.fsdafdscsa.com/";
    selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, baseUrl);
}

@Test
public void testA9() throws Exception {
    selenium.open("");
    selenium.click("link=Sign In");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    selenium.type("id=login_username", "fsadfsa");
    selenium.type("id=login_password", "asweqr");
    selenium.click("name=login_button");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    verifyTrue(selenium.isElementPresent("link=Sign Out"));
    selenium.click("link=Trade");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    String sellButtonText = selenium.getText("xpath=(//button[@type='button'])[7]");
    System.out.println(sellButtonText);


    assertNotEquals("Loading...", selenium.getEval("storedVars['sellButtonText']"));
    String buyButtonText = selenium.getText("xpath=(//button[@type='button'])[8]");
    System.out.println(buyButtonText);
    assertNotEquals("Loading...", selenium.getEval("storedVars['buyButtonText']"));
    String bidPrice = selenium.getText("id=pretty_bid_price");
    System.out.println(bidPrice);
    assertNotEquals("Loading...", selenium.getEval("storedVars['bidPrice']"));
    String askPrice = selenium.getText("id=pretty_ask_price");
    System.out.println(askPrice);
    assertNotEquals("Loading...", selenium.getEval("storedVars['askPrice']"));
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    selenium.stop();
}
}
```

The code is failing at the first assertNotEquals. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with Java and Selenium, but to me it looks like you're trying to access something within the storedVars array that you stored in a string:

```
String sellButtonText = selenium.getText("xpath=(//button[@type='button'])[7]");
```

and then later

```
assertNotEquals("Loading...", selenium.getEval("storedVars['sellButtonText']"));
```

Shouldn't you use somthing like `selenium.store` if you want to use the `storedVars` array?

Answer (score 0):

In my java automation framework, I use the WebDriver$Timeouts.class interface - implicitlyWait(long time, TimeUnit unit)method.  In you case, exactly after you initialize an instance of the object Webdriver, paste the below code:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This method specifies the amount of time the driver should wait when searching for an element if this is not immediately present.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try dynamically waiting for something on the page to load.

```
selenium.wait("id=login_username")
```

then also try this as mentioned in one of the answers.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

you can play around by increasing the seconds. Depending on the required sla for the page to load. i.e. Some pages may take longer than 30 seconds to load.